# Gevent/Flask app not listening on external IP on Windows 2012 R2

Tags: networking, windows-server-2012-r2

Windows 2012R2 server with the only installed feature being IIS which is listening on port 80.

I have a GEvent/Flask application that listens for inbound TCP connections on 5000 (and exposes a REST API), and cannot work out why inbound connections are not routing to the application. This is what I have checked:

1. The application is started and listening on port 5000
2. An inbound port rule is configured to allow all inbound TCP traffic on port 5000. I've more or less rules out this as an issue, as the config is identical to other ports which do route correctly and the steps outlined below fail even if the firewall is entirely disabled.
3. DNS is correctly configured, confirmed by Remote Access working and the IIS server responding to web requests on port 80 when targeted by DNS name
4. Confirmed with network guys that no firewall or filtering exists in front of the server

The following tests from Internet Explorer demonstrate the problem:

1. IE running on the server, connect to `'http://localhost'`. SUCCESSFULLY HITS IIS
2. IE running on the server, connect to `'http://localhost:5000'`. SUCCESSFULLY HITS THE APP
3. IE running on the server, connect to `'http://servername:5000'` shows 'page can't
   be displayed'. FAILS
4. IE running on remote machine, connect to `'http://servername'`. SUCCESSFULLY HITS IIS.
5. IE running on remote machine, connect to `'http://servername:5000'` shows 'page can't be
   displayed.' FAILS.

I'm at a loss as to what to check next, any suggestions on what could be blocking the traffic to port 5000?

Thanks
Ian

Comment: Open the TCP ports and then set right bindings, https://docs.jexusmanager.com/tutorials/binding-diagnostics.html#background

Comment: Surely that for the situation where you want the traffic to the TCP port to route into IIS? That's not the outcome I want, I want the traffic to route directly to the application listening on port 5000.

Comment: The same applies to that application. If it only listens to localhost traffic, the behavior you observed is perfectly normal (you can reproduce the same error with IIS if you use localhost bindings). Thus, time to check the application's manual or talk to its technical support.

Comment: It's an application I wrote, so I am the user manual :-) It's simply binding to a TCP port, so I don't understand how/why it would ever know/care that the route in was via localhost, IP address or DNS entry. It'd all just resolve to the IP address, no?

Comment: It's an application I wrote, so I am the user manual :-) It's simply binding to a TCP port, so I don't understand how/why it would ever know/care that the route in was via localhost, IP address or DNS entry. It'd all just resolve to the IP address in the IP layer, no? Netstat is showing the app as bound to the single IP address of the server on port 5000.

Comment: Then it depends on how you wrote it, and that's more a Stack Overflow question. Most application frameworks (like ASP.NET Core/Kestrel) have specific settings for that (like https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/fundamentals/servers/kestrel?view=aspnetcore-3.1#endpoint-configuration)

Comment: Thanks that was helpful, you were right the Gevent framework had defaulted to binding only to localhost, though for life of me I can't see that 'feature' in their documentation. If you want to add an answer I'll mark it as accepted.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To handle incoming TCP/IP traffic, it is important to open the TCP/UDP port(s) on Windows Firewall. But that's just the first step. After that, the application must hook itself to that port and set up a binding to handle incoming packets.

In your specific case, HTTP packets for `http://servername:5000` are rejected, not because of the firewall, but because that your application does not set up a proper binding at port 5000. Requests at `http://localhost:5000` works, so we can assume that its binding is in fact on `localhost:5000` only, as a result only localhost traffic can be handled.

To resolve this, you have several options,

- Modify your application to bind to `*:5000` (or `+:5000`),
- Or set up a reverse proxy (like nginx) to bridge external traffic to `localhost:5000` (in fact, that's why many frameworks by default take only localhost traffic, as they expect developers to set up a reverse proxy in front).

Answer (score 1):

Further to Lex Li's answer, in this specific situation the GEvent package was selected as the production deployment option for a Flask app inline with the Flask production deployment options given [here](https://flask.palletsprojects.com/en/1.1.x/deploying/).

This configuration was chosen specifically to avoid the complexity of  a fully fledged web server such as IIS or a reverse proxy.

The Flask documentation gives the following example for deploying an application using GEvent:

```
from gevent.pywsgi import WSGIServer
from yourapplication import app

http_server = WSGIServer(('', 5000), app)
http_server.serve_forever()
```

The issue that is not clearly documented is that this configuration still only binds to the localhost, despite being listed under the section for production deployments.

The following modification to the example code causes the application to correctly bind to the external IP address on port 5000:

```
from gevent.pywsgi import WSGIServer
from yourapplication import app

http_server = WSGIServer(('0.0.0.0', 5000), app)
http_server.serve_forever()
```